# Ubuntu: syslog full with protocol family 39

Tags: ubuntu

On an appliance with Ubuntu 12.04LTS I have /var/log/syslog full with

```
NET: Registered protocol family 39
NET: Unregistered protocol family 39
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction what that protocol family is. I looked around, but found no clue.

Additionally, dmesg tells me:

```
dmesg: klogctl failed: Bad address
```

It doesn't display any logs.

In essence this is an appliance where the only thing that runs are a few application servers (Java).

Is it possible that both (problems) are related?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a 3.5 kernel I now found this while digging through the sources at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/socket.h?v=3.5:

```
 #define AF_NFC          39      /* NFC sockets                  */
 ...
 #define PF_NFC          AF_NFC
```

On older kernels that may not exist.

What it now means is still unclear, I will update my answer as investigations proceed.

Oh and apparently, there is a bug with some kernels where lots of messages in the kernel log make dmesg behave the way I've shown. Indeed the "lots" of logs here are the ones about protocol family 39. So yes it is related.